# How to display Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder in WinJS?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am trying to make an app that applies filter effects on images. From FilePicker I can get a IRandomAccessStream and I can convert it to BitmapDecoder. But I am not sure how to diplay the bitmap data as image? I do not want to use the file name or path, just want to display the BitmapData as an image. What control should I use in WinJS and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These MSDN blogs explain the following process in more detail
http://goo.gl/izCdf
http://goo.gl/OLgfn

I found a way to create a BitmapEncoder from a BitmapDecoder. That encoder can be used to create a in memory stream that can be displayed in a  field.

```
       internal async Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> applyFilterInternal()
    {
        inputStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);

        var memStream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var encoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(memStream, decoder);

        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 640;
        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 480;
        encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;

        // Fant is a relatively high quality interpolation algorithm.
        encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;

        // Attempt to generate a new thumbnail from the updated pixel data.
        // Note: Only JPEG, TIFF and JPEG-XR images support encoding thumbnails.
        encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated = true;

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        return memStream;
    }

public IAsyncOperation<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> applyFilter()
    {
        Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> from = applyFilterInternal();
        IAsyncOperation<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> to = from.AsAsyncOperation();
        return to;
    }
```

To display this -

```
            filter.applyFilter().then(function (memStream) {
            var msStream = MSApp.createStreamFromInputStream("image/jpeg", memStream);
            var imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(msStream);
            id("imageInput").src = imageURL;

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert an IInputStream or IRandomAccessStream to an image with `MSApp.createStreamFromInputStream()` and `URL.createObjectURL()`:

```
var path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + "\\thing.jpg";
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync(path).then(function (file) {
    file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read).then(function (randomStream) {

        // Convert the stream to MS-Stream.
        var msStream = MSApp.createStreamFromInputStream("image/jpeg", randomStream);
        var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(msStream);

        var img = document.getElementById("theImage");
        img.src = imageUrl;

    }, onError);
}, onError);
```

The HTML should look like this:

```
<img id="theImage" src="#" />
```

Comment: Kiewic, I appreciate your answer. But the actual problem I am facing is that I need to exract IRandomAccessStream from BitmapDecoder object. I tried couple of methods that are provided but I am unable to do so.